# Struggling with SQL Pivot Query Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Anyone tell me whats wrong with my SQL, having a hard time with this today. The error is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3) as [month], year(TransactionDateTime) as [year],
        count(*) as Total 
    FROM quotations
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Total)
    FOR [year] IN (select distinct year(TransactionDateTime) from quotations)
) AS pivot
```

The shape I am after is... So years as column names then 12 rows for each month. Below is just to illustrate the shape

```
        //   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        //  ['Month', '2013', '2014', '2015'],
        //  ['Jan', 10, 30, 31],
        //  ['Feb', 11, 30, 32],
        //]);
```

Comment: query seems ok to me, I think pivot is a reserved word so better to use some other alias or at least add brackets: as [pivot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for pivot is as follows ([From TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)):

```
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column], ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```

You can see that inside `IN` clause there should be column names enclosed in `[]` which can be a problem if the column names are dynamic. This problem can be easily solved by using dynamic SQL.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(year(TransactionDateTime))
            FROM Quotations
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 
    'SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3) as [month], year(TransactionDateTime) as [year],
            count(*) as Total 
        FROM quotations
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total)
        FOR [year] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS pivot'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

I don't know what your schema is so there may be a mistake with table/column names. If this doesn't help I can be more precise if you share your schema and a sample data.

Comment: I added one line 'group by  left(datename(month,TransactionDateTime),3), year(TransactionDateTime)' in after 'FROM Quotations' in your solution and it WORKED! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following part of your query

```
(select distinct year(TransactionDateTime) from quotations)
```

You need to provide a static list of years inside the in clause.